# sendBackwards which would not pass a certain object (fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to make so that an object with the name of mainImage would work as a background image and no other object could pass it when the user would try to use "sendBackwards" method.

So, in my thinking I need to know that

```
1.If the mainImage is at index 0
2.If active selected object is at index 1 when I should not allow to use sendBackwards
```

This is what I tried so far, but I guess you will be able to see where this is failing:

```
   $scope.getActiveIndex = function() {
           for (var i = 0; i < canvas.fabric._objects.length; i++) {
            console.log("not active");
               if (canvas.fabric._objects[i].status === "active") {
                console.log("active");
                   return i;
               }
           }
       }

       $scope.sendBackwards = function() {
            var currentObject = canvas.fabric.getActiveObject();

                 for (var i = 0; i < canvas.fabric._objects.length; i++) {
console.log($scope.getActiveIndex());
                if (canvas.fabric._objects[i].name === "mainImage" && $scope.getActiveIndex() == 1) {
                    console.log("Can not pass the background");
                    return;
                } else {
                    canvas.fabric.sendBackwards(currentObject);
                }
    }
            canvas.fabric.renderAll();
    };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this quite easily:

```
  $scope.sendBackwards = function() {
        var currentObject = canvas.fabric.getActiveObject();
        var zIndex = canvas.fabric.getObjects().indexOf(currentObject);
    if (zIndex == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
             canvas.fabric.sendBackwards(currentObject); 
    }

    canvas.fabric.renderAll();
```

};